# validation custom message for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Rails has introduced new way to validate attributes inside model. 
When I use

```
validates :title, :presence => true
```

it works but when I try to add a custom message

```
validates :title, :presence => true,:message => "Story title is required"
```

an error is generated

```
Unknown validator: 'message'
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Try this

```
validates :title, presence: { message: "Story title is required" }
```

Comment: How do I remove the :title from the error message above? Above displays as "Title Story title is required". I want "Story title is required." Thanks.

Comment: Where has the `=> true` gone in this answer? Is it not necessary?

Comment: @dukedave oddly enough it is not necessary. You can pass anything 'truthy' to `presence`.

Comment: Another potential answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966263/rails-custom-validation-message

Comment: If you're too lazy to visit the link above (like me) you could use instance_variable_name.errors[:title] to access your custom message in your view. Not a solution if your using full_messages() though

Comment: @NotDan, link broken.

Comment: @Mayumi - You can remove the attribute name from the message by writing a manual validation and adding the error to `:base`, for example `errors.add(:base, "Story title is required)`

Comment: @Mayumi Change the values in `/config/locales/en.yml` and add keys like `en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        agree_tos: "Terms of Service"` Or leave the name of the field blank. Sorry no newlines in comments. You'll figure it out.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, I did this in a better way. If you want to remove the field title from the message you should use this on your _form.htmk.erb view:

As you can see inside this view:

```
<ul>
  <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Replace it by:

```
<ul>
  <% @article.errors.each_with_index do |msg, i| %>
  <li><%= msg[1] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A custom message for a boolean with conditionals might be:

```
validates :foo,  inclusion: { in: [true, false], message: "cannot be blank" }, if: :bar?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES of rails 3 . 
For example in above case, it will be like :

```
HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
:title => "story"
}
 def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

It will give you error message, replacing model attribute title with story.