# Rails: Custom validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to make a simple custom validation message. The validation I'm using compiles and runs fine, but I don't see any change in the message:

`validates :rating, :inclusion => { :in => 0..5 }, :presence => { :message => " must be within 0-5" }`

The message I get is still `Rating is not included in the list`

I need to validate that `rating` is present and is a `decimal` between `0-5`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alright, I solved it. This is the validation that works:

```
validates :rating, :inclusion => { :in => 0..5, :message => " should be between 0 to 5" }
validates :rating, :presence => { :message => " cannot be blank" }
```

and I added this

`validates :rating, :numericality => { :message => " should be a number" }`

Comment: right, reference here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html Should have looked before, +1 though

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of the field name prefix?

Comment: To get rid of the field name prefix you can use `message: nil` and it won't have any message for that validation