# Rails: Strange validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a `Location` model with fields:

`Location(id: integer, name: string, address: string, latitude: decimal, longitude: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, rating: decimal, rating_count: integer)`

In my `location` model, i have the following validations (which work fine):

```
attr_accessible :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :rating, :rating_count

validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :address, :presence => true
validates :rating, :inclusion => 0..5
validates :rating, :presence => { :message => " cannot be blank" }
```

I also have a `Post` model with fields:

`Post(id: integer, user_id: integer, location_id: integer, info: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: date time)`

And the following validations:

```
attr_accessible :info, :address, :name, :rating
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :location
attr_accessor :rating, :address, :name #Virtual attributes for the Post create form

validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :address, :presence => true
validates :rating, :inclusion => 0..5
validates :rating, :presence => { :message => " cannot be blank" }
```

Now, **the issue is** that when I try to create a new `Post`, the validations for `name` and `address` work fine (just as they work for `Location`), but the validation for `rating` always fails. Even when I enter a `rating` of '3', I get the error `Rating is not included in the list` for some reason, although a `rating` of '3' is validated correctly if used directly with the `Location#create` action.

Does anyone know why only the `rating` validation isn't working as expected with `Post`, even though it works fine with `Location`, and the other validations behave identically with the two models ?

EDIT: Here's the `create` action from `posts_controller`:

```
def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
@location = Location.find_by_address_and_name(params[:post][:address], params[:post][:name])

if @location.nil?
  @location = Location.find_by_address(params[:post][:address])
end

#If the address and the name of the location is the same, just update the rating for that location, and associate the post with the location
if (@location && params[:post][:name] == @location.name)
  @post.location_id = @location.id
  @location.rating_count += 1
  @location.rating = ( (@location.rating + params[:post][:rating].to_r.to_d )/ @location.rating_count )
else
  @post.location_id = Location.create(:address => params[:post][:address], :name => params[:post][:name], :rating => params[:post][:rating].to_r.to_d).id
end

@post.save


respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    @location.save! #Update the location only if the post was successful
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

I know this is a LARGE post, but the main point is, 2 identical validations are failing in one place and succeeding in another. One of them validates attributes which are part of the database, the other validates virtual attributes, and I suspect this is the underlying problem.

Comment: can you show us the code where you actually do the creation, please?

Comment: @jaydel I have pasted the code from the controller.

Comment: don't forget to accept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966263/rails-custom-validation-message

Comment: There is nothing to do with your validation line. Rails is smart enough to convert integers

Comment: @apneadiving Yes, I tried that. Same error: `Rating is not included in the list`

Comment: there is no save before your `AFTER SAVE`

Comment: @apneadiving Sorry, that is a relic of earlier code. I moved the save statement to save only if `@post.save` is successful. I will remove the `logger.info` lines from the post.

Comment: @AnkitSoni let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2320/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-ankit-soni)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :rating, :inclusion => ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
# OR
validates :rating, :inclusion => (0..5).map(&:to_s)
```

**UPD**

add this method

```
def rating=param
  @rating = param.to_f
end
```

so now you can use your original validation

```
validates :rating, :inclusion => (0..5)
```

Comment: I'm using the exact same validation in my Location model, so the validation itself shouldn't be a problem. Also, `rating` is a decimal, not an integer.

Comment: @Ankit Soni, in your Loaction model `rating` is an atrribute, while in Project it is virtual attribute - feel the difference

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there would be a difference concerning validations in the 2 cases. The 2nd validation you provided works, but the issue is I need to validate `:rating` to be a `decimal` between 0-5, but not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Would you mind explaining why the method was needed?

Comment: This method is just converting your string (for ex.: "1.34") to float number (decimal), so `"1.34".to_f => 1.34`. We have used simple setter here. When you've created new `Post.new(:rating => "1.3", :title => "Blah" ...)` our setter have converted our `rating` value into float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store an integer value `3` in rating, not the string `"3"`.

Something like:

```
model.rating = params[:rating].to_i
```

Comment: I added `.to_r.to_d` in the relevant places (`rating` is a decimal, not an integer)