# Rails presence validation fails on value 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model similar to the following,

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :admin

    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :admin, :presence => true
end
```

The name property is a string and the admin property is defined as a boolean in the migration.

If I try to create an instance of the model in the console using,

```
a = Activity.create(:name => 'Test', :admin => 0)
```

Then the validation fails saying I need to provide a value for Admin. Why? I have supplied a value.

I could understand if I had failed to supply a value at all or if I had supplied nil. But why does a value like 0 (or even false for that matter) cause validation to fail?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`validates :presence` uses `blank?` to determine whether a value is present. But `false.blank?` => true. So the validation fails, because `blank?` is telling ActiveRecord that no value is present.

You can rewrite this as:

`validates :field_name, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }`

as recommended in [Rails Guides: ActiveRecord Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

see also [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Makes sense to me I guess. But I guess I still don't agree that false.blank? or 0.blank? should return true

Comment: Fair enough, but you'll have to take that up with the guys who wrote Rails :)

Comment: +1. The solution works. But I too wish Rails handled this better. The error message when using the solution here is `:upgraded_kitchen_bathrooms=>["is not included in the list"]` which is horrible considering the simplicity of what we're after.

Comment: Well it was pretty easy to fix my complaint about the error message: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7011116/135101

Comment: I agree that false.blank? is not the same as "is a value present?"  Thanks for posting this, finally it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4/5

```
validates :name, absence: true
```