# Customize error in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have messages error from 
`render :json=> {"status"=>"failed",:errors=>@user.errors.messages}.to_json`

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "errors": {
        "Email": [
            "has already been taken"
        ],
        ,
        "Username": [
            "has already been taken"
        ]
    }
}
```

But i want to custom error:

```
{
        "status": "failed",
        "errors": {
            "error": [
                "Email has already been taken"
            ],
            ,
            "error": [
                "Username has already been taken"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank for your support.

Comment: Try accessing the Email and UserName value from `@user.errors.messages` and you cant index two values with the name "error"

Comment: why do you need this json structure? If you just want to change the message content, you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966263/rails-custom-validation-message

Answer (score 0):

You be able to implement method `my_custom_errors_messages` in the `User` model. Or in the module and include it in your models. Where you will change errors has whatever you want.

You also could take a look at [`full_messages()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages) it might help you.

Comment: please give me detail your solution.Thank so much.

Comment: What kind of details? Define method, use enumerable method like `map` and prepare Hash you want.

Comment: Read about modules: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html Read about enumerable:  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html